# How to fix commands concatenation when enqueuing ConcurrentQueue<string> in unity3d c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, tcp

Good day.
Wrote 2 applications communicating with each other over TCP. One is a server (tablet), the second is a client (windows).
To synchronize multithreading, I used the standard ConcurrentQueue queue class.
However, I noticed strange behavior when sending messages. When added to a queue, commands are concatenated, although commands are sent in turn.
it's look lite two commands(2 string) executing at one time, then concatenating, then enqueuing 2 queue.
Look like this:
[image]

Comment: could you show your code maybe? Without it it is hard to tell what's happening ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP doesn't do messages. TCP does streams. The problem isn't the concurrent queue - it's how you read the string.

One send can result in multiple receives on the other side. Multiple sends can result in a single receive. That's how TCP works.

To send messages over TCP, you have to use message framing - have a way of dividing the stream of bytes into individual messages.

There's two extremely simple (and stupid) message framing approaches:

- Terminate each message with a special terminator value. This is often used in text-based TCP protocols, and the terminator is often something like `\n`
- Prefix each message with its length. The reading then becomes a loop of "read message length, then read *length* of bytes".

But in the end, TCP is complicated. If you can, use a ready networking library instead of trying to deal with TCP directly, something like Lidgren. These allow you a much more high-level approach to networking code - e.g. having messages, some reliable, some unreliable etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
    string[] arr = clientMessage.Split('\n');
    foreach (string item in arr)
    {
         if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
             recievedCommands.Enqueue(item);
     }
```

Big Thanks !